# visual c++ wrong optimisation

Tags: c++, visual-c++, optimization, compiler-construction

I have doubly linked list:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16185759/list.h

and method in other class:

```
List<int> get_vertices()
{
    Element<Edge*> *curr = edges->head;
    List<int> vertices;
    int v1, v2;

    while (curr != 0)
    {
        v1 = curr->data->v1;
        v2 = curr->data->v2;

        if (vertices.has(v1) == false)
        {
            vertices.insert(v1);
        }

        if (vertices.has(v2) == false)
        {
            vertices.insert(v1);
        }

        curr = curr->next;
    }

    return vertices;
}
```

method has not called according to debug.

compiler ignores it, substituting the value false, if you remove at the end return false, then everything works.

What to do?
thanks in advance

Comment: Where does the head variable come from, is it a class method? Oh sorry, my mistake=)

Comment: Maybe your `head` is actually `0`... ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please, post complete, minimal program that reproduces the problem you have. Tell us what output you get and what you expect.

Comment: Sounds like a case of UB, but where...?

Comment: Your `data` isn't floating point by any chance, is it?

Comment: "compiler ignores it, substituting the value false" how did you get to that conclusion?

Comment: tried to run debug, it turned out that the function is not called, because the breakpoint is ignored.

Comment: The function is not called on debug mode and you assume its substituting the value? One may expect that kind of things from release builds, but not from debug ones. Probably the function is just not being called.

Comment: I gave the code of the List and the method caller has.

Comment: Prefer to use `std::list` as it has already been tested and debugged.  Saves you tremendous amout of development time.

Comment: I wrote my class list for a long time and just wanted to use it. just strange that does not work, even should

Comment: std:: list does not contain a method that I need.

Comment: Shouldn't that second vertices.insert call be passing v2 and not v1?

Comment: oh. This was the whole problem ... I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `return` at the end it *appears* to work, because you've induced undefined behavior and the compiler can do whatever it wants: In this case it's returning true by random chance.

The problem doesn't appear to be in this code but most likely the `operator==` for the data type you're storing doesn't exactly match the intended item in the list. This could be true for floating point or user data types.

Comment: Curr pointer is of type Element <T>, data is the same type, then the data of one type.

Answer (score 0):

If you used [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), you could run `g++ -fdump-tree-all` and get a lot (hundreds) of dump files containing a textual presentation of GCC internal representations, so you would understand what optimizations are happenning

Comment: Really? Is there an implication from "get a lot (hundreds) of dump files containing a textual presentation of GCC internal representations" to "you would understand what optimizations are happenning"? Seems incredibly counter-intuitive to me...

Comment: The point is to understand which dump file is it interesting to look into, and this depends upon which optimizations are involved. But I believe that these dump files explain more what optimizations did than just looking into the gnenerated assembly code.

Comment: Which only helps if you've got some idea about what gcc is doing internally. Those files are usually used to help debug problems with incorrect/not optimal code, so the target audience doesn't really overlap. Assembly is universal and would be rather short in this case, so that seems simpler

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual C++, then by default debug builds will have no optimization so this is not likely to be an optimization error.

I would assume a more likely result is that the debug symbols are not being reloaded correctly. You can check this by throwing a hard error within the function, and if the error is thrown you DO know that the code is being reached.

I would suggest using [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) to print debug output to the console rather than relying on just breakpoints.

That said, question to your question: Is there a reason you are not using the [Standard Template Library list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/)?

Also, I am somewhat concerned that the compiler is even ALLOWING you to have a function with a bool return, with no defined return. What warning level is your compiler set to? (I'm concerned you or someone else lowered it, and you are missing key warnings)

Comment: I agree with Keeper, failing to hit a break point that you 'know' is being executed is often a symbols issue.  

You perhaps should try a 'rebuild all' and see if it starts hitting your break point.  

If it still doesn't hit the break point then using some kind of log, trace, or printf style debugging to figure out what is happening.